# Automate the Restore database process using crontab in MYSQL server(OS - linux)

Tags: mysql, linux, database, cron, restore

I am trying to automate the restore MySQL database stored in server A (OS - windows) to MySQL server database in Server B (OS-Linux) using crontab.

So far, I have used the following script to restore the database manually in server B:

MySQL -u root -p < //HFSDC-01/user/mysql.sql

The challenge is I am unable to find a way to restore it automatically over the night.

I can't set up automation using crontab because the database is stored in windows server A which takes and stores backup every 2 hours and I want to restore the latest backed up file to server B at the time of restoration.

So far, I have away, I can select the latest file in the backup folder using Powershell and transfer it to any new folder in another directory and schedule it in task scheduler, and then I can set up a crontab procedure which will restore that only file in the new folder and restore it directly.

But now the issue is that i can't find a script which can automatically select that latest backup file in new folder in server A automatically and restore it in server B (The script must run in Linux crontab only)

Comment: Have you considered using the [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) capabilities already built in to MySQL?

Comment: @Luuk This is not (not-related) details. This is a production issue of a client which needs to be solved. I would not bother to post this if this is not important.

Comment: Just let me know if you didn't understood any part of question, I 'll rephrase it according to your understanding

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yes, i am also thinking of using Mysql replication now.
Can it happen between different versions of MySQL??
Like source is of 5.6 version and destination is 5.7 or higher??

Comment: The only problem is see in this question has nothing to do with the title, it is the problem in your last sentence where it says: "But now the issue is that i can't find a script which can automatically select that latest backup file in new folder". Due to the complex description, i am not sure if you need a Windows solution for this problem, or a Linux solution for this  problem.

Comment: @user14755618 I don't know. That's the sort of thing the folks over at [DBA.se] are probably better able to answer.

Comment: @luuk The solution i want is a script in Linux that will select the backup file saved in windows and restore it automatically

Comment: @user14755618: Does the Linux system have access to the Windows file system? (You are not sharing much info on this problem.)